# Clojure Performance, How to Type hint to r/map

Tags: performance, clojure, type-hinting, reducers

Below, I have 2 functions computing the sum of squares of their arguments.  The first one is nice and functional, but 20x slower than the second one.  I presume that the r/map is not taking advantage of aget to retrieve elements from the double-array, whereas I'm explicitly doing this in function 2.

Is there any way I can further typehint or help r/map r/fold to perform faster?

```
(defn sum-of-squares
  "Given a vector v, compute the sum of the squares of elements."
  ^double [^doubles v]
  (r/fold + (r/map #(* % %) v)))

(defn sum-of-squares2
  "This is much faster than above.  Post to stack-overflow to see."
  ^double [^doubles v]
  (loop [val 0.0
         i (dec (alength v))]
    (if (neg? i)
      val
      (let [x (aget v i)]
        (recur (+ val (* x x)) (dec i))))))

(def a (double-array (range 10)))
(quick-bench (sum-of-squares a))
```

800 ns

```
(quick-bench (sum-of-squares2 a))
```

40 ns

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why not use [`areduce`](https://clojure.github.io/clojure/clojure.core-api.html#clojure.core/areduce):

```
(def sum-of-squares3 ^double [^doubles v]
  (areduce v idx ret 0.0
           (let [item (aget v idx)]
             (+ ret (* item item)))))
```

On my machine running:

```
(criterium/bench (sum-of-squares3 (double-array (range 100000))))
```

Gives a mean execution time of 1.809103 ms, your `sum-of-squares2` executes the same calculation in 1.455775 ms. I think this version using `areduce` is more idiomatic than your version.

For squeezing a little bit more performance you can try using unchecked math ([`add-unchecked`](https://clojure.github.io/clojure/clojure.core-api.html#clojure.core/unchecked-add) and [`multiply-unchecked`](https://clojure.github.io/clojure/clojure.core-api.html#clojure.core/unchecked-multiply)). But beware, you need to be sure that your calculation cannot overflow:

```
(defn sum-of-squares4 ^double [^doubles v]
  (areduce v idx ret 0.0
           (let [item (aget v idx)]
             (unchecked-add ret (unchecked-multiply item item)))))
```

Running the same benchmark gives a mean execution time of 1.144197 ms. Your `sum-of-squares2` can also benefit from unchecked math with a 1.126001 ms mean execution time.

Comment: Thanks Rodrigo.  I wasn't aware of areduce.  That's exactly what I needed, a way to tell a reduction to use aget...

Answer (score 7):

Before experiments I've added next line in project.clj:

```
:jvm-opts ^:replace [] ; Makes measurements more accurate
```

Basic measurements:

```
(def a (double-array (range 1000000))) ; 10 is too small for performance measurements
(quick-bench (sum-of-squares a)) ; ... Execution time mean : 27.617748 ms ...
(quick-bench (sum-of-squares2 a)) ; ... Execution time mean : 1.259175 ms ...
```

This is more or less consistent with time difference in the question. Let's try to not use Java arrays (which are not really idiomatic for Clojure):

```
(def b (mapv (partial * 1.0) (range 1000000))) ; Persistent vector
(quick-bench (sum-of-squares b)) ; ... Execution time mean : 14.808644 ms ...
```

Almost 2 times faster. Now let's remove type hints:

```
(defn sum-of-squares3
"Given a vector v, compute the sum of the squares of elements."
[v]
(r/fold + (r/map #(* % %) v)))

(quick-bench (sum-of-squares3 a)) ; Execution time mean : 30.392206 ms
(quick-bench (sum-of-squares3 b)) ; Execution time mean : 15.583379 ms
```

Execution time increased only marginally comparing to version with type hints. By the way, version with [transducers](http://clojure.org/transducers) has very similar performance and is much cleaner:

```
(defn sum-of-squares3 [v]
  (transduce (map #(* % %)) + v))
```

Now about additional type hinting. We can indeed optimize first `sum-of-squares` implementation:

```
(defn square ^double [^double x] (* x x))

(defn sum-of-squares4
  "Given a vector v, compute the sum of the squares of elements."
  [v]
  (r/fold + (r/map square v)))

(quick-bench (sum-of-squares4 b)) ; ... Execution time mean : 12.891831 ms ...

(defn pl
  (^double [] 0.0)
  (^double [^double x] (+ x))
  (^double [^double x ^double y] (+ x y)))

(defn sum-of-squares5
  "Given a vector v, compute the sum of the squares of elements."
  [v]
  (r/fold pl (r/map square v)))

(quick-bench (sum-of-squares5 b)) ; ... Execution time mean : 9.441748 ms ...
```

Note #1: type hints on arguments and return value of `sum-of-squares4` and `sum-of-squares5` have no additional performance benefits.

**Note #2**: It's generally bad practice to start with [optimizations](http://c2.com/cgi/wiki?PrematureOptimization). Straight-forward version `(apply + (map square v))` will have good enough performance for most situations. `sum-of-squares2` is very far from idiomatic and uses literally no Clojure concepts. If this is really performance critical code - better to implement it in Java and use interop. Code will be much cleaner despite of having 2 languages. Or even implement it in unmanaged code (C, C++) and use JNI (not really maintainable but if properly implemented, can give the best possible performance).

Comment: Thanks.  I'm aware that my v2 is not idiomatic, but the code is very performance sensitive (trillions of calculations) and I'd hate to have to reach for java everytime I have a patch of hot code.  I would naturally prefer to use a generic clojure-esque version, but even a 10:1 performance slowdown is quite significant.  So for this particular application I'll stick with my v2.  I was just trying to have my cake and eat it too...approach the performance of v2 with the elegance of your transducers v3.

Comment: In other words, I'm treating v2 AS a piece of interop, without the overhead of 2 languages.